# In which memory is saving Java ClassLoader instance

Tags: java, heap-memory, classloader, permgen

I want to know where the ClassLoader instance is saving, in which memory. Is it  saving in heap or in permgen? And if I have a custom ClassLoader( for example JasperReports loads his own ClassLoader which calls JRClassLoader ), instance of it is also saving in heap memory or in permgen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classloader is not an exception from the rules, so:

- `ClassLoader` instance is created on heap,
- `ClassLoader` class is like any other class it is created on permgen (till Java 7)

Comment: ok, thanks for answer. Also I want to ask, when the  GC is unloading classes from permgen.

Comment: I think this is not explicitly defined. You can be sore that **classes from permgen will be removed just before the OutOfMemoryException might be thrown**.

Comment: Not sure what @Crazyjavahacking is talking about in the comment. In theory you could have a custom ClassLoader that uses soft references to it's loaded java.lang.Class:es, which would mean they get garbage collected before OOME in case there are no instances of them or other references to them, or there may be garbage collectors / options that behave this way, but this _should not be assumed to be the case_.